# UDP broadcast on all interfaces with broadcast answer

Tags: linux, udp, posix, broadcast

I have a hardware device connected on one of the available network interfaces (in general don't know which one) that answers to UDP broadcast messages with UDP broadcast messages. I need to be able to send a message and receive the broadcast answer.

From other topics on stackoverflow, I've been able to get part of it to work, but not both send and receive simultaneously. Currently I do the following:

- For each interface listed by `getifaddrs(&ifaces)` with `iface->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET`
- Create a socket with `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)`
- Set the socket to broadcast with `setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, ...)`
- `bind()` to the address in `ifaces->ifa_addr` of `getifaddrs()` with 0 as port (first free port)
- Send, with `sendto()`, a packet to `INADDR_BROADCAST` from each of the opened sockets
- In n parallel threads (one for each socket) I wait for answers with `recvfrom()`

So, I fired up wireshark and the message gets sent correctly to all interfaces, the hardware answers in broadcast (255.255.255.255) correctly on the same port from which the packet was sent, but `recvfrom()` never returns data, it just waits. With the same code, if I bind to `INADDR_ANY` instead of `ifaces->ifa_addr` and run `sendto()` on the actual IP of the hardware instead of `INADDR_BROADCAST`, the broadcast answer gets caught without problems.

What exactly is going on? Why isn't the answer caught in the first case? How can send **and** receive in broadcast on multiple interfaces?

By the way, root access is not an option, so I can't do `setsockopt(..., SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "ifacename")`. And the OS is Linux.

Comment: The concept doesn't seem wrong, so a minimal program with the same behavior might be more useful. As to sending and receiving, you'll need to use something like `select()` to poll the socket(s) to see which have data pending to read. Otherwise, there's not much special about the process.

Comment: I found this thread http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=5722 which actually has a take on this problem (with a code example). Apparently, on Linux, if you bind to an address which is not `INADDR_ANY` you're not going to be able to receive broadcast UDP messages. I'll be damned if I know why. I can replicate the problem by running ./bcast 127.0.0.1 and ./bcast - on another shell.
Interestingly on OS X it does work, though.

Comment: So, another hack/solution that comes to mind is to bind all the sockets to the same port by using `setsockopt(..., SO_REUSEPORT, ...)`, and then bind an extra one to `INADDR_ANY`, again with the same port. Hopefully all the broadcast answers would be multiplexed to the last socket?

Comment: You can checkout my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623057/udp-broadcast-using-gcdasyncudpsocket-through-all-available-network-interfaces

May this helps you out.