# UDP broadcast using GCDAsyncUdpSocket through all available Network Interfaces

Tags: objective-c, macos, sockets, networking, gcdasyncudpsocket

I am using GCDAsyncUdpSocket for broadcasting UDP packets for searching my NAS devices.

Below is the code snippet for sending and receiving UDP packets

```
NSString *broadCastAddress = @"255.255.255.255";
NSInteger udpPort =  8097;

GCDAsyncUdpSocket  *gcdAsyncUdpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc]  initWithDelegate:selfdelegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[gcdAsyncUdpSocket bindToPort:udpPort error:&error];
[gcdAsyncUdpSocket setPreferIPv4];

NSData *data = @“Hi there”; // Sample data
[gcdAsyncUdpSocket  enableBroadcast:YES error:&error];
[gcdAsyncUdpSocket  beginReceiving:&error];

[gcdAsyncUdpSocket  sendData:data toHost:broadCastAddress port:udpPort withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
```

The above code can send packets through only single Network interface i.e either Wifi or Ethernet or Thunderbolt, the thing is i want to broadcast through all of the available Network Interfaces.  (Ethernet, WiFi, Thunderbolt etc.).

Is there any way i can broadcast via all the available Network Interfaces (Ethernet, WiFi, Thunderbolt etc.) at the same time and using the same port.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Phew!! I figured out a solution after lot of googling and trial & error methods. Here goes the solution.

1. First enumerate all the available Network interfaces using the below function.

   ```
   - (NSMutableArray *) enumerateAndGetDetailsOfAllNetworkInterfaces
   {
        NSMutableArray *interfaceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        struct ifaddrs *ifap, *ifa;
        struct sockaddr_in *sa;
        char *addr;

        getifaddrs (&ifap);

         for (ifa = ifap; ifa; ifa = ifa->ifa_next)
         {
          if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET)
           {
            QNInterfaceModel *interfaceModel = [[QNInterfaceModel alloc] init];

            sa = (struct sockaddr_in *) ifa->ifa_addr;
            addr = inet_ntoa(sa->sin_addr);
            printf("Interface: %s\tAddress: %s\n", ifa->ifa_name, addr);

            interfaceModel.interfaceName = [NSString stringWithCString:ifa->ifa_name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            interfaceModel.interfaceIPAddress = [NSString stringWithCString:addr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            [interfaceArray addObject:interfaceModel];
       }
   }

     freeifaddrs(ifap);
     return interfaceArray;
   }
   ```

I have created InterfaceModel which stores the Interface Name and its Address.

Step 2: Create a Socket for each Interface

```
    NSMutableArray *interfaceArray = [self enumerateAndGetDetailsOfAllNetworkInterfaces];

    for(QNInterfaceModel *interfaceModel in interfaceArray)
    {
       NSError *error;

       NSInteger udpPort =  8097;

       GCDAsyncUdpSocket *gcdAsyncUdpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                                         delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
       [gcdAsyncUdpSocket bindToPort:udpPort interface:interfaceModel.interfaceName error:&error];

       gcdAsyncUdpSocket.delegate = self;

       if(error == nil)
       {
         [_socketArray addObject:gcdAsyncUdpSocket];
       }
    }
```

Step 3: Store all the created sockets in a array and broadcast through each of them as follows, but before broadcasting, we need to create a listener socket to receive the response packets.

```
     NSError *error;

     NSString *broadCastString = @"255.255.255.255";

     NSInteger udpPort =  8097;
     GCDAsyncUdpSocket *listenerGCDAsyncUdpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                                  delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [listenerGCDAsyncUdpSocket bindToPort:udpPort error:&error];
    [listenerGCDAsyncUdpSocket setPreferIPv4];
    [listenerGCDAsyncUdpSocket  enableBroadcast:YES error:&error];
    [listenerGCDAsyncUdpSocket  beginReceiving:&error];


   // Send Packets through all the available Interfaces
   for(NSInteger i =0 ; i<_socketArray.count ;i++)
   {
    GCDAsyncUdpSocket *gcdAsyncUdpSocket = [_socketArray objectAtIndex:i];
    gcdAsyncUdpSocket.delegate = self;

    if(error)
    {
       // Error connecting
    }
    else
    {
        [gcdAsyncUdpSocket setPreferIPv4];

        NSData *data = @"Hi There";

        if (![gcdAsyncUdpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:&error]) {

            QNDLog(@"Error enableBroadcast:%@",error);
            return;
        }

        [gcdAsyncUdpSocket  beginReceiving:&error];

        [gcdAsyncUdpSocket  sendData:data toHost:broadCastString port:udpPort withTimeout:-1 tag:i];
    }
}
```